# Jquery - reload element and children

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$(".roulette-area").load(location.href+" .roulette-area>*","");
```

which works great for reloading the element however I also need to reload all the children of `.roulette-area`.

How would I do this?

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZvVjz

Comment: Can you give an example of your DOM structure? Question is very light on details.

Comment: Call me crazy but I cannot understand how the question relates to the example or vice versa...

Comment: The example is what I have inside my `.roulette-spinner` element, sorry should have been clearer. I'll update it all.

Comment: New example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZvVjz

Comment: The whole example is in a div called  `.roulette-spinner` but the question is about loading something to `.roulette-area` which I don't see in the example at all. Can you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: `line 125` in the JS of the example contains `$(".roulette-area").load(location.href+" .roulette-area>*","");` This reloads the `.roulette-area` element, however I need to also do the same for each of the children

Comment: if you spin the wheel then look what happens to the roulette wheel after you'll see what my issue is

Comment: Why would resetting the children be necessary? `$(".roulette-area > *").load(location.href+" .roulette-area>*","");` like that?..I don't see any `.roulette-area` in the HTML.

Comment: Have you considered just making the entire roulette wheel an object and just removing it from the DOM at the end of the spin and instantiating a new one in default state when ready for the next spin rather than trying to reset all of the DOM elements individually?